# How should you send a password from a pure html/javascript application to a php page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-services, encryption

I'm trying to create a login system where multiple applications are able to login using the same web service.  This "web service" is just a web page written in php.  Ideally, the applications could sed up the username and password to the web service, which would check the values against the encrypted database values, and then return either true or false for logged in (more than that, but you get it).

However, as you read that, you probably instantly noticed I said "send password to the web service", which is really really bad if you don't do it correctly.  I don't want to send a decrypted password over get/post for obviously security reasons.

What is the best/most secure method of sending a password from a pure html/javascript application up to a php web service?  I am very new to this sort of thing so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Send the data over an HTTPS connection. Building your own encryption between the client and server isn't necessary.

Comment: You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them. Also, don't try to build this secure connection yourself, that's what SSL is for. A simple `POST` over SSL will be good enough.

Comment: @JonKoops so it's literally as simple as sending it via post to `https://foobar.net/my/web/service.php` instead of `http://foobar.net/my/web/service.php`?

Comment: Yes. It will handle the encryption for you. For getting started with HTTPS Let's Encrypt is a great tool: https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should you send a password from a pure html/javascript application
>   to a php page?

The standard and secure way is to send data over an `HTTPS` connection, for that you'll need to install an `ssl` certificate on your domain. SSL certificates used to cost money but in our days you can get them free at https://letsencrypt.org/